# JavaScript arrays adding last element instead of recently added input

Tags: javascript

Good evening. I am new to JavaScript and I need help with my mini-project and I have only one issue here and it is in the this.Add = function ().
It works properly when I enter a duplicate value from my list therefore it displays an alert that no dupes are allowed. But... when I enter a unique value, it only adds up the last element present (Wash the dishes) from myTasks list. instead of the one I recently entered and the list goes on adding the same ones. Did I just misplace something?
This is my final activity yet and I want to finish it to move to the next function. Thank you in advance.
[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tasks CRUD</title>
  <style>
    #tasks{
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="app.Add()"> 
  <input type="text" id="add-task" placeholder="Add another card">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<div id="tasks" role="aria-hidden">
  <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
    <input type="text" id="edit-task">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
  </form>
</div>

<p id="counter"></p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
    <tbody id="myTasks">
    </tbody>
</table>
</center>

<script>
var app = new function() {

  this.el = document.getElementById('myTasks');

  this.myTasks = ['Clean the bathroom', 'Wash the dishes'];

  this.Count = function(data) {
    var el   = document.getElementById('counter');
    var name = 'task';

    if (data) {
      if (data > 1) {
        name = 'Things To DO';
      }
      el.innerHTML = data + ' ' + name ;
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name;
    }
  };
  
  this.FetchAll = function() {
    var data = '';

    if (this.myTasks.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < this.myTasks.length; i++) {
        data += '<tr>';
        data += '<td>' + this.myTasks[i] + '</td>';
        data += '<td><button onclick="app.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
        data += '<td><button onclick="app.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
        data += '</tr>';
      }
    }

    this.Count(this.myTasks.length);
    return this.el.innerHTML = data;
  };

  this.Add = function () {
    el = document.getElementById('add-task');
    // Get the value
    var task = el.value;
    
    if (task ) {
      for(task of this.myTasks)
      {
        var ctr = 0;
        if(document.getElementById("add-task").value == task){
          ctr = 1;
          break;
        }

      }
      if(ctr == 1)
      {
        window.alert("Duplicates not allowed.");
      }else{
         // Add the new value
      this.myTasks.push(task.trim());
      // Reset input value
      el.value = '';
      // Dislay the new list
      this.FetchAll();
      }  
     
    }
       
  };

  this.Edit = function (item) {
    var el = document.getElementById('edit-task');
    // Display value in the field
    el.value = this.myTasks[item];
    // Display fields
    document.getElementById('tasks').style.display = 'block';
    self = this;

    document.getElementById('saveEdit').onsubmit = function() {
      // Get value
      var task = el.value;

      if (task) {
        // Edit value
        self.myTasks.splice(item, 1, task.trim());
        // Display the new list
        self.FetchAll();
        // Hide fields
        CloseInput();
      }
    }
  };

  this.Delete = function (item) {
    // Delete the current row
    this.myTasks.splice(item, 1);
    // Display the new list
    this.FetchAll();
  };
  
}

app.FetchAll();

function CloseInput() {
  document.getElementById('tasks').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML too.

Comment: I now added the HTML :)

Comment: You may want to be careful with the pitfalls associated with different equality operators `==` and `===` in javascript too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop:

```
for (task of this.myTask) {
}
```

You are not declaring a new task variable, but instead assigning to the outer `task` variable, hence the repeated addition of tasks already in your list.

You can declare a new variable in the for scope like so:

```
for (const task of this.myTask) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I still lack knowledge in other functions and this will really add up. Thank you so much..

Comment: In that case, I use ```let``` for readability :)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML as it is.

And your Javascript goes like below. You have a bug while checking if the task already exists in the array. As you're comparing string value either use simple for loop with triple equals or do as i have attached below.

```
var app = new function() {
    
      this.el = document.getElementById('myTasks');
    
      this.myTasks = ['Clean the bathroom', 'Wash the dishes'];
    
      this.Count = function(data) {
        var el   = document.getElementById('counter');
        var name = 'task';
    
        if (data) {
          if (data > 1) {
            name = 'Things To DO';
          }
          el.innerHTML = data + ' ' + name ;
        } else {
          el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name;
        }
      };
      
      this.FetchAll = function() {
        var data = '';
    
        if (this.myTasks.length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < this.myTasks.length; i++) {
            data += '<tr>';
            data += '<td>' + this.myTasks[i] + '</td>';
            data += '<td><button onclick="app.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
            data += '<td><button onclick="app.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
            data += '</tr>';
          }
        }
    
        this.Count(this.myTasks.length);
        console.log(this.myTasks.length);
        return this.el.innerHTML = data;
      };
    
      this.Add = function () {
        el = document.getElementById('add-task');
        // Get the value
        var task = el.value;
        console.log(task);
        
        if (task ){ 
                        var arrayContainsTask = (this.myTasks.indexOf(task) > -1);
           
            if(arrayContainsTask == true){
                    window.alert("Duplicates not allowed.");
            }else{
                // Add the new value
                this.myTasks.push(task);
                // Reset input value
                    el.value = '';
               
          }  
         
          // Dislay the new list
          this.FetchAll();
        
           
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Cool. This one is also great! Thank you for your help. I will make sure I'll get good in JS soon.